# Push a random character from an array into another array

Tags: javascript

```
var legalCharactersForSaveCode = ["B","C","D","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z", "+", "/",];
var saveCode = [];

function generateSaveCode() {
 for(var c = 0; c > 30; c++){
   v = Math.round(Math.random() * legalCharactersForSaveCode.length);
   saveCode.push(legalCharactersForSaveCode[v]);
 }
  saveCode.push(store.get("money"));
  alert(saveCode);
}
```

I'm trying to make it so it pushes a random character.
When I ask it to alert the saveCode array all it does is alert the money.
(I'm using store.js)

I was expecting for it to push a random characters from the legalCharacters array into the saveCode array.

Comment: Your `for` loop is flawed, it should read `c < 30` not `c > 30` as it won't ever be greater than 30 as it's set to zero at the beginning of execution.

Comment: `Math.round` is not a valid substitution for `Math.floor`. Using round would cause accidentally referencing an undefined index.

Answer (score 1):

Your "for" loop does not work as the condition is c > 30, and should be c < 30